# Null pointer access: The variable "tipoEstablecimiento" can only be null at this location

Tags: java

I've been searching in the Internet about this error with no result. I'm lost with it. Anyone can help with it?

```
.
.
.

  TipoEstablecimientoHotel tipoEstablecimiento  = null;
.
.
.
.
try{
  tipoEstablecimiento.setCodigo("");  <--- Line with the error.
}catch (Exception e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
.
.
.
```

Of course I have the imports that I need (I mean for TipoEstablecimiento), and it marks that line with the corresponding warning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you initialized the object anywhere, or is that part of your omitted code?

Comment: Well, obviously I've created the corresponding java class for that purpose. I said I have the correct imports, but good question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us enough code, but I'd go with the error you got. You don't initialize the variable between assigning null to it and calling its `setCodigo` method so you'll surely get a NullPointerException (you cannot dereference a null object). Make sure you instantiate it before using it by calling its constructor, something like:

```
tipoEstablecimiento = new TipoEstablecimientoHotel();
```

Comment: Than check what is this error, and fix the problem, if you don't know how, ask here (a new question, with details and relevant code) we will all be happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're trying to call a method via `tipoEstablecimiento` - and whatever is coming up with the warning has proven that the variable can't possibly have a non-null value - so it will *always* throw a `NullPointerException`.

You need to assign a non-null value to the variable somewhere...

Comment: Well, I initialize that type to null, because at this moment I can't declare it as the normal way, I mean with: TipoEstablecimientoHotel tipoEstablecimiento = new TipoEstablecimientoHotel();

Comment: @elvenbyte: So how would you expect it to ever work? You should be grateful that the compiler / IDE / whatever is warning you that your code is never going to work at execution time - but giving you that warning at compile time. And *why* can't you call a constructor?

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the class, before calling its method.

> TipoEstablecimientoHotel tipoEstablecimiento  = new TipoEstablecimientoHotel();

Answer (score 2):

The IDE or compiler is telling you that you are never setting `tipoEstablecimiento`. In otherwords, that line that you are pointing at is absolutely guaranteed to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Set the variable to some instance of `TipoEstablecimientoHotel` to avoid the error.

Comment: Based on your response to others, what constructors exist for the type (or extending types)? Think of it like a String. `String x = "abc"; x.toUpperCase();` is not going to fail because it really is really saying: `"abc.".toUpperCase()`. However, `String x = null; x.toUpperCase();` will fail because it is saying `null.toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do a setCodigo. TipoEstablecimiento is NULL, not an object this class.
First you must instantiate an object

Comment: Before you execute setCodigo, you must do something like: TipoEstablecimientoHotel tipoEstablecimiento = new TipoEstablecimientoHotel();